# ios-Trying to draw points on image and then connect them through lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, touchesbegan

i can draw points on my image using the code in touchesbegan. and i am storing my coordinates in NSMutable array. i want it to draw lines as i mark points on the screen.. but my drawRect isnt firing i guess .. can u please tell me what to do..

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    int *count = 0;
    if([pointarray count]!=0)
    {
        float firstpointx= [[pointarray objectAtIndex:0]floatValue];
        float firstpointy= [[pointarray objectAtIndex:1]floatValue];
        float secondpointx= [[pointarray objectAtIndex:2]floatValue];
        float secondpointy= [[pointarray objectAtIndex:3]floatValue];

        //NSMutableArray *coordinates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i<=[pointarray count]; i++) {
            CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, firstpointx, firstpointy);///move to ur first dot
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, secondpointx, secondpointy);//add line from first dot to second dot

            CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
            [pointarray removeAllObjects];//remove first two points from ur array so that next line is not drawn in continuous with previous line
        }

        count++;

     }
}



-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    pointarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    CGPoint curPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.map];
    [pointarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.x]];
    [pointarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:curPoint.y]];
    [_map setNeedsDisplay];

    [self logMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sending : %@", pointarray]];
    NSLog(@"the point array is %@",pointarray);
    NSArray *coordinates = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:pointarray copyItems:YES];
    NSLog(@"the coordinate array %@",coordinates);

    //[self.map setNeedsDisplay]; // calls drawRectMethod

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(curPoint.x, curPoint.y, 10, 10)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.map addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: Tip: for this purpose is easier to use UIBezierPath.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `setNeedsDisplay` from this method:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}
```

Comment: You probably mean setNeedsDisplay.

Answer (score 1):

On `touchedBegan:withEvent:` you just call `setNeedsDisplay` on `_map`, not on `self`, that's why the view doesn't get redraw.

Also, you just add two points, but in `drawRect` you code like if it's sure that the array contains four points. Probably what you want to do is to add two points in `touchesEnded:withEvent`? If so you should call `setNeedsDisplay` from there.